# error migration down no existe tabla proyectos.FK_bitt_proy

Tags: php, yii

hi I'm trying to migrate down but I get the following error Exception: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1051 Unknown table 'projectos.fk_bitt_proy'

```
$this->addForeignKey('FK_bitt_proy', 'Bitacoratiempos', 'idProyecto', 'Proyectos', 'idProyecto');

public function safeDown(){
   $this->dropTable('FK_bitt_proy','Bitacoratiempos');
}
```

which I do not understand because it refers to the projectos table if the key is in bitacoratiempos

Comment: `dropTable` takes 1 argument, not 2, and `FK_bitt_proy` is the name of your foreign key, not a table name.

Comment: Ok yes, I made a mistake is dropForeignKey()